# Error # 0x89731706 while trying to deploy an application to a Windows CE device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have an application that I created a while ago for some unknown portable device (by portable I mean pocket pc and such). I finally got the device I needed, which is a MC3000 from Motorola, which runs on Windows CE 5.0 instead of Windows Mobile, which I initially developed for. When I try to deploy the solution, I get 0x89731706 from the "Device Connectivity Component" file. I tried cleaning the solution and restart it in case it was still hooked up on the emulator.

I created a deployment project for the application and it seems that there is something missing (it tells me "Cannot find 'x' or one of its components...)

I already developed applications for MC9090 and I never even had something close to this as a problem (except when the device was unplugged of course)

Does anybody knows the answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some search, I found out that it's simply because the device itself doesn't have much space, so I had to give it more ROM instead of RAM to even install the framework.

A rather hollow victory because now it has pretty much no more ram...

Answer (score 1):

*As this answer is in the first results from Google when searching for this error, I think that this may be helpful for someone looking for a different answer, as the accepted one didn't work for me.*

We have a .NET CF 3.5 project for Windows Mobile 5 PocketPC in VS2008, and were getting this error.

The problem was that everyone in the team had disabled UAC except the user of the computer that was throwing the error, and also forgot to run VS2008 as Administrator. As soon as we ran VS2008 as Administrator, the problem was gone.

Hope this helps to someone looking for a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem. I have been looking for a long time. Then, I founded this link: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?493399-RESOLVED-NET-CF20-Error-Connect-to-device-failed

This solution worked for me.

I restarted my device.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider using the space provided for the answer to include useful info from your link.

Comment: Thanks for answering however, it is better to include the relevant code then just a link to it. It would also be great to have a short explanation.  See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more.